# Python: How to store result of a daterange on a var list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import datetime
import re
import pymongo
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(d, d1):
    for n in range(int ((d1 - d).days)):
        yield d + timedelta(n)

#conect bd
uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
database = client['db']
collection = database['currency']


d = input('Insert beginning date (yyyy-mm-dd): ')
d1 = input('Insert end date (yyyy-mm-dd): ')

#search bd
item = collection.find_one({"date" : d})
item1 = collection.find_one({"date" : d1})
d = collection.find_one({})
d1 = collection.find_one({})
datas = item['date']
datas1 = item1['date']

#conversão de string para objecto
dataObject = datetime.datetime.strptime(datas, "%Y-%m-%d")
dataObject1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(datas1, "%Y-%m-%d")

#range
for single_date in daterange(dataObject, dataObject1):
    print (single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

I want to make the output of this code into a var list if it's possible.
For example beginning date is 2018-05-07 and the end date is 2018-05-11 and the output is:

```
2018-05-07
2018-05-08
2018-05-09
2018-05-10
```

How do I put that into a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this part is generating the dates you want in a list:

```
#range
for single_date in daterange(dataObject, dataObject1):
    print (single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Change it to this:

```
mylist = []
#range
for single_date in daterange(dataObject, dataObject1):
    mylist.append(single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Answer (score 3):

this is faster than a simple for loop statment

```
my_list = [d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for d in daterange(dataObject, dataObject1)]
```

Comment: You can change the single_date temp var to something shorter to get this line under 90 characters, and pep 8 compliant.

    my_list = [d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for d in daterange(dataObject, dataObject1)]